# Disable daylight saving time

Tags: rhel, timezone

Using C functions (time and localtime) I am getting:

> timezone:18000
>   daylight:1 means :dl
>   timezone -24 (-360 minutes) GMT.

We do not want to add the daylight and keep using GMT -5 and not GMT -6.

Local time is a symbolic link to `/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Jamaica`

How we can check where daylight saving time is set and disable it? The system is RHEL 5.4.

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: LSB_VERSION="1.3"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 3 (Taroon Update 5)

LSB Version:    1.3
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseES
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 3 (Taroon Update 5)
Release:        3
Codename:       TaroonUpdate5

Linux 2.4.21-32.0.1.ELhugemem #1 SMP Tue May 17 17:43:22 EDT 2005 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: DST stuff is regulatory and evidently applies in Jamaica.  Maybe you should say where you actually are, or the place where you want your clock set to.  It's a matter of changing the timezone, not disabling DST.  Timezones are not simply +/- values relative to GMT (see `man tzfile`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the Time Zone Configuration tool GUI:

```
# redhat-config-date
```

or use the command line utility:

```
# timeconfig
```

Either way, you need to set the timezone to `Etc/GMT-5`